# vim: setting mouse cursor, line number and clipboard copy without line numbers all at once

Tags: shell, vim

I use `vim` for all my coding and was wondering to use the following features but getting troubles in configuring my .vimrc file

1. using mouse pointer for cursor : set mouse=a    (works perfectly)
2. using line numbers : set number  (works perfectly)
3. copy to clipboard : `does not work` as expected.

Reason: because " set mouse=a "  keeps it into visual mode.

Workaround : press and hold shift and then select the text : works OK

`Problem` : because I press shift and hold it, the line numbers are also getting copied to the clipboard and 
pasting it wont be of help as those line numbers need to be removed. ofcourse i can unset it and remove line numbering temporarily, but i dont want to do it for every file i open.

So I need :

1. mouse support for cursor
2. line number support
3. copy to clipboard (`without`) line numbers

any solutions ? (I did try a combination of this and that from other questions, but couldnt get it done)

Comment: What is the output of `:echo has('clipboard')` and what is your OS?

Comment: output is 0. i use linux (ubuntu and suse linux

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu, run this command in a terminal to install a proper Vim:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install vim-gnome
```

On Suse, look for the "gvim" package.

Once you are done, you can use `"+y` to yank to your system clipboard and `"+p` to paste from it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the clipboard to work in VIM works different in different Operating Systems. In [my vimrc](https://github.com/munen/vim_setup), I have it set up for OSX and Linux and it works nicely in both. In Linux I can just yank lines and they will be in the clipboard, on the Mac when I use MacVim I can use CMD+C (works out of the box) or when run in the console, I use c.

This is the required vimrc setup. When running Linux, you can of course just use the last two lines. When running Windows and using GVim, CTRL+c should work out of the box, as well.

```
"Clipboard
if os == "darwin"
  "Fast copying to clipboard in visual mode
  vmap <leader>c "*y<cr>

  "Fast cutting to clipboard in visual mode
  vmap <leader>x "*x<cr>
elseif os == "Linux"
  set clipboard=unnamed
  set clipboard=unnamedplus
endif
```